# parameters do not pass to function within a function

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres functions to create a crosstab table.

My first dynamic query function (dynamic_crosstab) creates a sql select statement, and then this select statement gives the final result on execution.
*dynamic_crosstab functions works perfectly*

I need to execute this select query (result of dynamic_crosstab function) by using parameters, so I am again using a function again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION primary_cross(
    date,
    date,
    integer)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare
val_1 text;
begin
select * from dynamic_crosstab('select 
        p.location_id, p.employee_id, pt.description, sum(p.hours_allocated) as hours_allocated
    from
        preference_type pt, preference p, preference_date_etl pde, date_etl de
    where
        pt.id = p.preference_type_id and
        pde.preference_id = p.id and
        pde.corporation_id = $3 and
        de.id = pde.date_etl_id and
        pde.deleted = ''''N'''' and
        p.deleted = ''''N'''' and
        pt.deleted = ''''N'''' and
        de.local_date between ''''$1'''' and ''''$2'''' and
        p.employee_id IN (
            select id from employee where user_id IN (select id from app_user where corporation_id = $3))
    group by p.location_id, p.employee_id, pt.description',
'select distinct description from preference_type where corporation_id =$3',
'text','location_id int , employee_id int',false) INTO val_1;
return val_1;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Note that dynamic_crosstab function uses 4 input parameters. 2 sql queries, 2 text value and a boolean.

Now the problem is that parameters are passed correctly to first input of dynamic_crosstab function but they do not pass to the second input of dynamic_crosstab which is:

```
'select distinct description from preference_type where deleted=''''N'''' and corporation_id =$3'
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  there is no parameter $3
LINE 1: ...ct description from preference_type where corporation_id =$3
                                                                     ^
QUERY:  select distinct description from preference_type where corporation_id =$3
```

Please advise how i can use the parameters to make this work.

Thank You.